# How to run a C program using the following statement "filename -i inputfile.txt -o outputfile.txt"

Tags: c

I am currently working through a workbook on learning C. I am stuck on an exercise where it states that it requires me to use the following statement

**filename -i inputfile.txt -o outputfile.txt**

while running on command prompt.

Any help on the code behind this or some clarification as the workbook doesn't help.

Comment: lookup `main(int argc, char **argv)` and `getopt`

Comment: First lesson for learning C: C is not C++ is not C. They are different languages. Please don't add unrelated tags to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%d. %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When you call exe file (for example, prog.exe) with args
`prog.exe filename -i inputfile.txt -o outputfile.txt`
you will get

```
0. prog.exe
1. filename
2. -i
3. inputfile.txt
4. -o
5. outputfile.txt
```

All passed parameters are in argv array.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested use argc, argv and i suggest using getopt
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html

take a look at this example for a sarting place

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.